# Unpacking ArrayRef into X separate arguments

Tags: perl

Given an arrayref that contains other arrayrefs, is it possible to zip the nested arrayrefs together using the zip function from [`List::MoreUtils`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List%3a%3aMoreUtils#zip-ARRAY1-ARRAY2-ARRAY3)?

For instance given this arrayref:

```
my $matrix = [
   [qw( 1  2  3  4)],
   [qw( 5  6  7  8)],
   [qw( 9 10 11 12)],
   [qw(13 14 15 16)],
   [qw(17 18 19 20)],
];
```

I would like to zip each row together so I can get the transpose. Expected output:

```
[
   [qw(1 5  9 13 17)],
   [qw(2 6 10 14 18)],
   [qw(3 7 11 15 19)],
   [qw(4 8 12 16 20)],
];
```

My initial attempts were:

```
# I had hoped the function would unpack the arguments
zip @$matrix; 
# ERROR: Not enough arguments for List::MoreUtils::mesh at spiral.pl line 17

# I thought this slice would suffice to unpack them
zip @$matrix[1..scalar @$matrix-1]; 
# ERROR: Type of arg 1 to List::MoreUtils::mesh must be array (not array slice)
```

I am sure there is a way to do this elegantly, I am just not seeing it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `zip` function is extremely annoying because it uses [a `(\@\@;\@\@\@...)` prototype](https://metacpan.org/source/ADAMK/List-MoreUtils-0.33/lib/List/MoreUtils.pm#L294) or something insane like that. You'd have to do an ampersand-call to override the prototype: `&zip(@$matrix)`.

However, you are trying to *transpose* the matrix, not to `zip` it (which would produce a continuous list like

```
[1, 5, 9, 13, 17, 2, 6, 10, 14, 18, 3, 7, 11, 15, 19, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20]
```

We could use an `natatime` iterator in conjunction with `zip`:

```
my $iter = natatime @$matrix, &zip(@$matrix);
my @transposed;
while (my @column = $iter->()) {
    push @transposed, \@column;
}
```

which works, but this is severely overthinking the problem. Let's just swap indices:

```
my $transposed = [];
for my $i (0 .. $#$matrix) {
    for my $j (0 .. $#{ $matrix->[0] }) {
        $transposed->[$j][$i] = $matrix->[$i][$j];
    }
}
```

Comment: My initial idea was that if I used the zip operator on all of the rows it would produce the transpose; I forgot that it would not generate a nested array. Swapping indices is much cleaner though. Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the `transpose` function of [`Array::Transpose`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Array%3a%3aTranspose):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Array::Transpose qw(transpose);

my $matrix = [
   [qw( 1  2  3  4)],
   [qw( 5  6  7  8)],
   [qw( 9 10 11 12)],
   [qw(13 14 15 16)],
   [qw(17 18 19 20)],
];

my @array=transpose($matrix);

use Data::Dump;
dd \@array;
```

Outputs:

```
[
  [1, 5, 9, 13, 17],
  [2, 6, 10, 14, 18],
  [3, 7, 11, 15, 19],
  [4, 8, 12, 16, 20],
]
```